# Does YouTube split revenue between video and audio artist?

Tags: youtube

Got a copyright claim, but I can still use the audio as label will monetize my video.

Does YouTube split revenue between video and audio artist? Will I ever get a penny as video creator?

Comment: Our site is more about *using* web applications from the perspective of an end user.  This is more of a question of Google's policies, etc., and, as such, I don't believe that it's on-topic here.  I'm not sure if there is a site on SE that would be able to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Revenue splitting is available for cover videos, if the right holder has enabled it.[[1]](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3301938?hl=en)

It is not available for most other types of content, so the answer to

> Does YouTube split revenue between video and audio artist?

is "no" in the vast majority of cases.